# Getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in iteration time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a function to find my items min and max price from DynamoDB database.

```
def getShopItem(pk, item):
    
    db = getDynamoDb()
    table  = db.Table('my_items_table')
    response = table.query(
        KeyConditionExpression = Key('pk').eq(pk) & Key('sk').begins_with(item['sk'])
    )

    priceList = []

    for i,product in enumerate(response['Items']):
      print(i)
      priceList.append(product['attr']['price'])
    max = max(priceList)
    min = min(priceList)

    data = {
       "pk": "PRODUCT",
       "sk": item['sk'],
       "min": min,
       "max": max
    }

    return json.dumps(data)
```

After after call function

```
for i,item in enumerate(items):
    shopItem = getShopItem('PRODUCT', item)
```

I have gotten below output, here for 1st product it's I am getting my output fine, but for 2nd product I am getting "'str' object is not callable"

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
{"pk": "PRODUCT", "sk": "CATG#smart_phone#SUBCAT#iphone#Name#iphone11", "min": "1400", "max": "1500"}

0
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_item_count_function.py", line 96, in <module>
    print(getItemsCount())
  File "get_item_count_function.py", line 91, in getItemsCount
    shopItem = getShopItem('PRODUCT', item)
  File "get_item_count_function.py", line 37, in getShopItem
    max = max(priceList)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Why I am getting `'str' object is not callable`

Now how can solve it ?

Comment: You are using `max` as a variable and as a function (that is overwritten), change the name of the variable to something else and it's done.

Comment: @piertoni Thanks a lot ! It has solved.

Comment: max and min are keyword in python use another name